# Last line to first line

Tags: bash

Wondering if you could help me out.
What I am trying to do is to move last line of the file to the second line of the file.

File records are changing dynamically so the last line is not hardcoded with line no.

Current `$FILE` output:

1. ---FOOTER---
2. data
3. status (no of records in data) `echo -e "\n$CALC"`

What I am trying to achieve after above file is produced is the below output:

1. ---FOOTER---
2. status (no of records in data) `echo -e "\n$CALC"`
3. data

`$CALC` grabs output of the file and does `wc -l`.

Status counts no of records in file by using an `env $CALC`, which is set after current file is produced. Obviously if I move `$CALC` before file data is recorded in the file `'wc'` will fail.

Is there a way to somehow move the last line from produced $FILE output and move it to the second line?

I figured out a bit which will delete last file (needed after copy of the last line to the second line is done )

```
sed '$d' < $FILE > tmp
mv tmp $FILE
```

Any hints answers appreciated

Comment: we have `tac` command to cat in inversly...good?

Comment: The question isn't about reversing the output, data can (guessably) be a number of lines.

Comment: Hi, not really. TAC will "reverse" the file and the output of it. What I need to have is to move this last line which contains proper output of $CALC and place it in the 2nd line of the $FILE.

Answer (score 1):

```
(head -1 input; tail -1 input; tail -n +2 input | head -n -1) > output
```

I’m sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

this awk oneliner works for your need:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(x=1;x<NR;x++){if(x==2)print a[NR];print a[x]}}' file
```

if you want to move the last line to some line other than 2nd, you can just change the `x==2` to other value.

test:

```
kent$  seq 5|awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(x=1;x<NR;x++){if(x==2)print a[NR];print a[x]}}'   
1
5
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thank You. its 100% working and does the work :) I will have this code revieved to understand better how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
last=$(tail -1 file)
sed -i.bak -e "2s/^/$last\n/" -e '$d' file

---FOOTER---
status (no of records in data) echo -e "\n$CALC"
data
```

Comment: Excellent many thanks all for such quick response. I will have those ways checked and confirm.
Cheers :)

Comment: Sure let me know if you run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

A pure Bash solution using an array:

```
mapfile  array < input

printf  "%s" "${array[0]}"  "${array[ -1]}" "${array[@]:1:${#array[@]}-2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed's holding space, I found the following one-liner solution:

```
sed  '$!H;$!d;$p;$g' < file >
```

The instructions are: Put all lines but the last one into sed's holding pattern, then delete them, then print the last line, and copy the contents of the holding space to the pattern space.

One small drawback though, this code inserts an empty line behind the two printouts (the LF-CR signs seem to appear at the beginning of the line).

However this can be solved with an additional dirty redirection:

```
sed  '$!H;$!d;$p;$g' < file > | sed '/^$/d'
```

Any corrections, remarks or advices would be welcome.